# Error thrown when running existing Laravel project on local server

Tags: laravel

UPDATE: I think updating to a newer php version (by updating homebrew) causes this problem... Could/should I update the Laravel version of the project I'm working on? Or install a lower php version? I have no experience with that...

I'm working on a Laravel project for quite some time no. All of a sudden an exception is thrown when starting the local server.

The ErrorException is: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

It points to a few lines in the routes/web.php file.

```
    ErrorException 

  trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteGroup.php:65
     61▕     {
     62▕         $old = $old['prefix'] ?? null;
     63▕ 
     64▕         if ($prependExistingPrefix) {
  ➜  65▕             return isset($new['prefix']) ? trim($old, '/').'/'.trim($new['prefix'], '/') : $old;
     66▕         } else {
     67▕             return isset($new['prefix']) ? trim($new['prefix'], '/').'/'.trim($old, '/') : $old;
     68▕         }
     69▕     }

      +6 vendor frames 
  7   routes/web.php:90
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::group(Object(Closure))

      +3 vendor frames 
  11  routes/web.php:91
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::group(Object(Closure))
```

This are the lines in the web.php file

```
    Route::middleware(['auth.isAdminPers'])->group(function () {

        Route::get('/admin/admin',function () {
            return view('admin.admin');
        });

        Route::get('admin/dienstverplaatsingen',[AdminDienstverplaatsingController::class,'index'])->name('admin.dienstverplaatsingen');
        Route::get('/admin/experiment',[gebruikerController::class, 'experiment']);
       
        Route::get('/admin/export',[AdminDienstverplaatsingController::class,'export']);
        Route::get('/admin/fietsritten', [AdminFietsritten::class,'index'])->name('admin.fietsritten');
        Route::get('/admin/fietsrittengrouped', [fietsrittengrouped::class, 'index'])->name('admin.fietsrittengrouped');
        Route::get('/admin/maaltijden',[AdminMaaltijden::class,'index'])->name('admin.maaltijden');
        Route::get('/admin/maaltijdengrouped',[maaltijdengrouped::class,'index'])->name('admin.maaltijdengrouped');

        Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){ 
            Route::get('/users/export', [UserController::class,'export'])->name('users.export');
            Route::resource('/users', UserController::class);
            Route::get('/appsettings', function(){
                return view('admin.settings');
            })->name('appsettings');
 });
    });
```

Comment: Please add all code in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. If this worked for some time, what has changed between the last working state and now?

Comment: don't put up images of code, code is text and belongs in your question as text in a code block ... did you upgrade your PHP version recently?

Comment: "I think updating to a newer php version (by updating homebrew) causes this problem" - what does that mean? Did you check whether your application is compatible with that new PHP version you are using?

Comment: I updated the php version without realizing the issues it would cause... I installed Brew PHP Switcher and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem earlier. The way I have solved it was by running `php artisan route:cache` before `composer install`. Keep in mind that I am using PHP 7.4 with Laravel 8.